# What are different ways for layout reuse in Stripes

Tags: java, inheritance, layout, jstl, stripes

In Stripes presentation framework for Java, rendering templates and supplying code sections to template can be done in several ways:

Code section can be defined in template using

- `<stripes:layout-component name="foo" />`
- `${foo}`

You can supply these components

- using `<stripes:layout-component name="foo">bar</stripes:layout-component>` inside `<stripes:layout-render ...></stripes:layout-render>`
- as parameters `<stripes:layout-render ... foo="bar">`

To make the idea even more complex, JSTL variables can be

- defined using JSTL `<c:set var="foo" value="bar" />`
- outputted using `<c:out value="${foo}">`

How are all these ways related to each other and each of those should be used?

Comment: I am not a big fan of Stripes layouts, you can nearly do the same thing with standard JSP tag files (so, why bother with stripes:layout?)

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some testing on which definition works with which way of output

Test result:

```
                parametrized    layout-component    <-- Outputted with
layout-render       OK                FAIL
layout-component    OK                OK

^
Defined with
```

I also did some testing using `<c:out>` and `<c:set>`

Verdict:

- Variable outputted using `layout-component` CAN NOT be defined with ANYTHING ELSE but `layout-component`
- Variable defined with `layout-render` seem to be just set as JSTL variable, nothing else

  - It is a way of passing string as-it-is from a template to a page
- Supplying a variable using `layout-component` defines JSTL variable, too

  - However, that CANNOT be changed before possible `layout-component` has outputted it
- Advantage of using `layout-component` is that it is inherited across multiple templates

  - say `home.jsp` renders `std-tmpl.jsp`, which renders `base.jsp`. In this case `home.jsp` can supply the variable setting `layout-component: foo` and it gets outputted where it is set in `base.jsp`
- For outputting a variable that is not supposed to include HTML, one should always use

  `<c:out value="${foo}" />`

  This will html escape the following characters: < > & ' "

All comments and other explanations are highly appreciated!